# Would a static reference to an IoC Container in an MVCApplication cause memory leaks?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, memory-leaks, inversion-of-control

I am experiencing memory leaks in an ASP.Net MVC 3 application and I suspect it may be an issue with the IoC container.

The MvcApplication creates a WindsorContainer object, populates it and then stores it in a static field like this:

```cs
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication, IContainerAccessor
{
  private static WindsorContainer container;

  protected void Application_Start()
  {
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(
      new WindsorControllerFactory(container));
  }
}
```

Is it correct here to hold on to the container in a static field? As far as I understand, the container itself only needs to live as long as the MVCApplication itself. Making it static would simply share it across multiple MVCApplication instances, so I wonder if it is being disposed incorrectly.

Comment: Not sure about Windsor specifically, but I've used both Unity and Ninject and found that child container per request works best. Why hold on to this container for the life of the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container can be created this way and stored in the application object as a static field. You can control the lifetime of objects create by the container (see this [page](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Windsor-Tutorial-Part-Seven-Lifestyles&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)). For a web application the usual lifetime is per request - example copied from the aforementioned page:

```
Kernel.Register(
Component.For<ISession>()
    .UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession())
    .LifestylePerWebRequest()
);
```

And in this case, you will never have to share it across multiple instances of `MvcApplication` class - there's usually one implementation of `HttpApplication` class in web application.

Comment: Okay, thanks. From experience, holding on to static values for no apparent reason has tended to be a cause of leaks, but maybe in this case it won't be an issue.

Comment: Having a static field is not always root of all evil.

Comment: I don't suppose it is, but having a static field means that the actual type is linked to the value, and might never be cleaned up if it needs to be.

Comment: In this context you can imagine an equal sign between the instance of HttpApplication class and the IoC container. IIS is in charge here, whenever the app is stopped/restarted, the resources held by container are released.

Answer (score 2):

When using Castle Windsor it's important to follow the [Register Resolve Release](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasePattern.aspx) pattern, since the container itself might track disposable objects (in order to be able to dispose them).

For ASP.NET MVC this means that the ControllerFactory should invoke Release from ReleaseController. This answer contains more explanation: [Explain the mysterious world of IoC and automatic Dispose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487028/explain-the-mysterious-world-of-ioc-and-automatic-dispose/6496126#6496126)

You may also want to dispose the container itself when the MvcApplication disposes...

Comment: This doesn't quite explain the answer to my question about the static field, but it is immensely useful. You might have just solved my memory leak problem. Thank you.